# unable to access NFS share(s)

Tags: nfs

Unable to access NFS shares on Ubuntu from Windows 7. It just acts like the share can't be found on network. (NET HELP MSG 1222)

on client:
added NFS features
tried "mount IP:/share z:" and the gui drive mapping
tried with and without "AnonymousUid""AnonymousGid" DWORDs under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default
firewalls are off

on server:
exportfs lists the shares.
mount shows "nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)" (I think that's normal?!?) have experimented with many options in:
/etc/exports
/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
/etc/default/nfs-common
tried forcing no NFS v 4 after each change I'm restarting nfs service and re-exporting

Is there a log I can look at somewhere?!? I've been trying to figure this out forever... Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once ran into a problem connecting to NFS shares from Windows 7.  For me, the solution was to do the following on my Windows machine:

1. Open group policy editor (type “edit group policy” in the windows search bar)
2. Expand the tree selection to Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies
3. Select the Security Options item
4. Disable the policy named “Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)”
5. Restart your computer

Comment: You're a freaking genius! Thank you! WHERE did you find this?!?

Answer (score 2):

As always look in `/var/log/syslog` first.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing relevant is there.

Comment: Or `var/log/messages` - depends on the distribution